# run node.js on AppFog?

Tags: node.js, appfog

I uploaded my files to AppFog and I went to the site I just created.
But it seems that the site loads only index.html.

My node.js file named server.js, maybe I should name it something else?
Help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the AppFog [official documentation](https://docs.appfog.com/languages/node) for getting Node up and running?